# Consuming multiple kafka topics in the same consumer class

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a spring boot project and I am spring-kafka to connect to the underlying kafka event hub.

I have to listen to 2 different topics in the same consumer class. I have two approaches to do so.

One is to have two kafka listeners like this:

```
 @KafkaListener(topics = "topic1")
public void consumeTopic1(String message) throws Exception {  
   //do something
  }

 @KafkaListener(topics = "topic2")
public void consumeTopic2(String message) throws Exception {  
   //do something
  }
```

Another approach is to have 2 topics in the same kafkaListener like this

```
 @KafkaListener(topics = {"topic1", "topic2"})
public void consumeTopics(String message) throws Exception {  
   //do something
  }
```

Since I am new to kafka, I am not sure what is the difference between the two approaches. Which one is performant  and resource effective.

One thing I am wondering about is that would it listen to both the topics on a single thread in both approaches or it would spawn a thread each to listen to these topics.

Using approach 1, I have had troubles with the consumer where I see some delays in the consumption of the topics.

Please suggest me based on your experience as I am pretty new to kafka

===============EDIT========
Kafka properties are in application.yml as follows:

```
 kafka:
    properties:
      topics:
        topic1: topic1
        topic2: topic2
    bootstrap-servers: server1,server2
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
      retries: 4
    consumer:
      group-id: mygroupid
      auto-offset-reset: latest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

Comment: can you show consumer config code

Comment: I actually don't have a consumerConfig. I just have a class marked with a service annotation in which I have two methods with KafkaListener annotations. Do I need to load some special consumer beans?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is best practice to consume messages from multiple kafka topics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46628946/what-is-best-practice-to-consume-messages-from-multiple-kafka-topics)

Comment: at least can you show the properties in `application.yml` or `application.properties`

Comment: Sure. I just edited my post with application.yml portion pertinent to kafka. Please take a look

Answer (score 0):

- The purpose of creating multiple topics is to spread the data, and
  subsequently, the processing of data, across multiple
  cores/processes/threads.
- Even then, you can start with a single    consumer for multiple
  topics until a delay is observed in processing    events in queue.
  Then you can separate them out.

Comment: How do you separate them out cuz I would want to separate them out.

Comment: Your first approach does exactly that! Each kafkalistener is a separate container which runs with its own thread/can be configured be concurrency

Comment: Would there ever be a reason to use concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory or a consumerFactory for this use case ?

Comment: You use a concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory when you have multiple partitions per topic and want to register a consumer per partition

Comment: One final question. Should I consume these topics from different consumer groups or same consumer group won't hurt ?

Comment: Recommended usage would be to have separate groupids per topic

Comment: Hi Simha, following the first approach in the question, is there a way to enforce my consumer class to finish reading all msgs from topic 1 first (assuming it is not frequently updating) and then go to topic 2?